# KeyError en login de diccionario

Tags: python

anteriormente estuve haciendo un login en diccionario y mejorandolo. Va todo perfecto, si meto bien el usuario pero mal la contraseña da salida a un mensaje ya establecido y hasta ahi genial. el problema viene si meto primero mal el usuario, la salida es la siguiente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pruebas.py", line 26, in <module>
    x = usuarios[User]["apellido"]
KeyError: 'Loren'
```

El código es el siguiente:

```
usuarios = {
        "iperurena": {
            "nombre": "Iñaki",
            "apellido": "Perurena",
            "password": "123123"
    },
        "fmuguruza": {
            "nombre": "Fermín",
            "apellido": "Muguruza",
            "password": "654321"
    },
        "aolaizola": {
            "nombre": "Aimar",
            "apellido": "Olaizola",
            "password": "123456"
    }
 }

User = input("Escriba su usuario: ")    
Pass = input("Escriba su password: ") 
x = usuarios[User]["apellido"]
intentos = 3

while(User != usuarios.keys() or Pass != usuarios[User]["password"]):
    intentos -= 1
    if intentos == 0:
        break         
    print(f"Acceso fallido, te quedan {intentos} intentos")
    User = input("Escriba su usuario: ") 
    Pass = input("Escriba su password: ")

if User in usuarios.keys() and Pass == usuarios[User]["password"]:
    print(f"Bienvenido {User} {x}")  

else:
    print("Acceso fallido, te quedaste sin intentos")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El principal problema está en la definición de `x` depende de que lo ingresado en el `input()` de `User` esté contenido en el diccionario. Esto se soluciona definiendo la variable `x` dentro de la validación que valida si ambos inputs son correctos, ahí es donde se necesita `x` para ese `print()`.

Otra observación que vale la pena hacer, es el mal uso que le estás dando a las estructuras condicionales, el `else` de el final se puede eliminar. Esto por que tienes un `if` dentro del ciclo principal que valida si los intentos equivalen a 0. En dicha validación se pude imprimir el mensaje por pantalla.

Una nota adicional, es mucho más cómodo manejar los datos de los usuarios en una lista. En un futuro las validaciones se tendrán que hacer iterando sobre el contenedor de los diccionarios, los diccionarios son conjuntos sin orden (no se puede iterar sobre ellos). De todos modos es solo un consejo, no sé las necesidades o propósitos de tu script.

Implementando lo anteriormente dicho, tu script puede ser mas eficiente si es modificado de la siguiente manera:

```
User = input("Escriba su usuario: ")    
Pass = input("Escriba su password: ") 
intentos = 3

while(User not in usuarios.keys() or Pass != usuarios[User]["password"]):
    intentos = intentos - 1
    print(f"Acceso fallido, te quedan {intentos} intentos")

    User = input("Escriba su usuario: ") 
    Pass = input("Escriba su password: ")

    if intentos == 0:
        print("Acceso fallido, te quedaste sin intentos")
        break 

if User in usuarios.keys() and Pass == usuarios[User]["password"]:
    x = usuarios[User]["apellido"]
    print(f"Bienvenido {User} {x}")
```

**Nota:** Por supuesto con los diccionarios en el mismo archivo.

Finalmente te adjunto una ejecución por terminal, con el fin de que veas el resultado obtenido:

```
Escriba su usuario: Cangrejo
Escriba su password: 1234
Acceso fallido, te quedan 2 intentos
Escriba su usuario: Ramiraa
Escriba su password: Ok
Acceso fallido, te quedan 1 intentos
Escriba su usuario: fmuguruza
Escriba su password: 654321
Bienvenido fmuguruza Muguruza
```

Espero que te haya servido, saludos!

Answer (score 2):

El usuario "Loren" no existe en el diccionario, lo que produce la falla.

Antes de intentar accesar el diccionario, tienes que asegurarte de que la llave exista, usando

```
if User in usuarios:
    x = usuarios[User]["apellido"]
```

Segundo, la línea

```
while(User != usuarios.keys() or Pass != usuarios[User]["password"]):
```

está mal: estas comparando el string `User` con la lista `usuarios.keys()`. Eso no tiene lógica ni sentido.

Lo que tienes que preguntar es

```
while(User not in usuarios or Pass != usuarios[User]["password"]):
```

Hay errores de lógica en el código que podrás encontrar cuando arregles los problemas de sintaxis.